# How to get input from command line argument

Tags: java, command-line

currently my file is run by me calling Java Server and then entering a port number after the program has started like this:

> java Server
>
> Port #:

I do this by creating a scanner in my main and just printing the prompt and waiting for input. and I can enter 7777 to set the port to 7777.

but how do I make it so I can just enter the port number like this?

> java Server 7777

I tried it on my current code but the number entered after server just doesn't do anything and I'll still have to enter it into the prompt after.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: You know that pesky entry point method your program's main class needs to have?  The one with signature `void main(String[] args)`?  The command-line arguments are provided in that array it receives as its parameter.

Comment: Can you provide us the code? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simple example from [this tutorial page](https://www.studytonight.com/java/command-line-argument.php) should help you.

```
class cmd
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    for(int i=0;i< args.length;i++)
    {
    System.out.println(args[i]);
    }
  }
}
```